# Renderer image in 3d scatter chart?

Tags: highcharts

i can't able to add image at my 3d chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

where i must add this code (for renderer image) ?

```
  function (chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30)
        .add();

});
```

thanks!

Comment: You can run the `chart.renderer.image` function anywhere after having created your chart. Works like a charm.

Comment: where ? i try but doesn't work :(

Comment: i did !!!!!! but why the picture doesn't rotate when i rotate the 3d chart???

Comment: Then you probably want to restate your question. Renderer works that way. It renders an image (in this case) to a specific place. Do you want a symbol for one of your points, or what is going to be the function of the image?

Comment: i want to add an image that it rotates, when i rotate the 3d chart...

Comment: If it can be a `Point` that will be your easiest option. See [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols).

Comment: what?? i don't understand...  i ask you if is there a way to renderer an image in my scatter 3d chart, and if when i rotate the chart, also the image rotates. Is possible?

Comment: @Ondkloss but is possible to change a symbol of point, but in 3d chart??

Comment: Yes, but they seem to not have correct depth in relation to eachother. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/52q9vypd/

Comment: Infact... Why? Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Ondkloss do you know if is possible to add to symbol of point, no an url but text ?